# Dropdown list based on pivottable on MS EXCEL by using Visual Basic

Tags: drop-down-menu, excel, range, pivot, vba

I'm using Microsoft Excel and VBA. 
I need a dropdown validation lists that depend on the selection done in a previous cell and those from the 4 subsequent selections. The dropdowns are based on named ranges, but these ranges are generated by pivot tables. As the content of the pivot tables could change, the named ranges don't match any more.

Is there a way to define the naming of the ranges in the pivot table automatically?

For a failure reporting system, I have a database of possible failure modes and causes. With each reported failure the corresponding failure mode and cause needs to be selected.
The database will contain hundreds of possible failure modes and causes, so it would be helpful only to show those failure modes and causes belonging to the selected system.

I guess it easier when I show the example file:
www.maasgeesteranus.nl/files/Example Excel input SDM codes and failmodes.xlsm

The pivot table contains the named ranges, which are put in manually, but this should be either by a macro-routine or it should be possible to call these pivot table ranges in the validation definition of the columns in the selection worksheet.

Comment: !!! Which programming language?

Comment: The application is in Excel with VBA

Comment: None can answer a question without specifying the programming language used!

Comment: When you said *As the content of the pivot tables could change, the named ranges don't match any more.*, do you mean column size? like the row numbers do not match anymore? e.g. previous there were 10 items from pivot to the name range, now only 5 items?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your current drop downbox is in `Sheet(1)` and it's being populated by `"A2:A10"` range which is named as `rangeA` and currently you only have items upto `"A6"`, so 5 items,

```
Dim LastRow as Long
Dim StartRow as Long

'--assume that your named range first row has no titles
StartRow = Sheets(1).Range("rangeA").Row '-- 2
LastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, _ 
          Sheets(1).Range("rangeA").Column).End(xlUp).Row '-- 6

If StartRow <> 1 then
StartRow = StartRow - 1
Lastrow = LastRow - StartRow
End if

ComboBox1.List = Sheets(1).Range("rangeA").Resize(LastRow).Value
```

Comment: For a failure reporting system, I have a database of possible failure modes and causes. With each reported failure the corresponding failure mode and cause needs to be selected.
The database will contain hundreds of possible failure modes and causes, so it would be helpful only to show those failure modes and causes belonging to the selected system.